# getting the last and first few elements in a list in python

Tags: python

I'm trying to divide a list, according to user input.
for example, I can get a list of

```
(["A","B","C","D"],num_of_groups)
>>>["AB","BC","CD","DA"]
```

my problem is with the last element. because like in the example, I need to take the last and first elements in a list (could be also last two and first three .. )

I tried doing so by adding all the element twice and then slicing, but then I have a problem that when the user wants a group of all elements, I'm returning two groups of the elements instead of only the one. I'll explain:

*this is what I'm doing*

```
list_copy = list(char_list)*2
#get the slice in the size of n.
slices.append(list_copy[i:i+n])
```

*this is what happaning when user eners a size same as the list size*

```
(["A","B","C"],3)

>>>["ABC","ACB","BAC","BCA","CAB","CBA","ABC","ACB","BAC","BCA","CAB","CBA"]
*instead of ["ABC","ACB","BAC","BCA","CAB","CBA"]
```

is there any other way of doing so? I would love some help!
thanks!

Comment: So for inputs `l = ['A', 'B', 'C']` and `n = 3`, you want `['ABC']` and not `['ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB']`? From your example first example, it seems you want the wrapping to occur.

Comment: I did mean ['ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB']..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the modulus operator `%` to start at the beginning when necessary:

```
>>> l = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
>>> [l[i%len(l)]+l[(i+1)%len(l)] for i in range(len(l))]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'da']
>>> [l[i%len(l)]+l[(i+1)%len(l)] for i in range(2*len(l))]
['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'da', 'ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'da']
```

Answer (score 0):

using the wonderful power of `zip`:

```
>>> l = ["A","B","C","D"]        
>>> for i in zip(l,l[1:]+l[:1]): print(''.join(i))


AB
BC
CD
DA
```

This may be confusing but what is essentially happening is iterating through 2 lists, your original one and a copy of your original where the each element is moved over one. You could also use this for a list comprehension:

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(l,l[1:]+l[:1])]
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA']
```

Comment: The second one seems to have `'DD'` as the last element rather than `'DA'`. Looks like a slice with `-1` rather than `1`.

Comment: my bad, didn't double check the list comprehension :P

Answer (score 0):

It's a little ambiguous as to what you're trying to achieve. In your first example, you wrap around to get `DA`, however in your last example you only want `['ABC']` and not perform the same wrapping to get `['ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB']`?

If you're looking to get the wrapping effect, then here's something you can do:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

def group(l, size):
  return [ ''.join(islice(cycle(l), i, i + size)) for i in xrange(len(l)) ]
```

Using [itertools.cycle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) is a little more convenient than doubling the list. Since you're working off an iterator instead of a list, you have to pair it up with [itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to do the slicing.

Here's the example output:

```
>>> group(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2)
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA']

>>> group(['A', 'B', 'C'], 1)
['A', 'B', 'C']

>>> group(['A', 'B', 'C'], 2)
['AB', 'BC', 'CA']

>>> group(['A', 'B', 'C'], 3)
['ABC', 'BCA', 'CAB']

>>> group(['A', 'B', 'C'], 4)
['ABCA', 'BCAB', 'CABC']
```